# Angular error in MEAN stack - Uncaught Error: $injector:modulerr

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am making a simple in MEAN stack, the code starts fine at the beginning, when I code a couple of lines more Angular shows me an error. What I am doing wrong? I cannot follow with the Internet MEAN stack courses for this issue.
PLease help with this issue.

> Html Code of index.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Contact list App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/metro-bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <section class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h1>This is a MEAN stack - Contact list!</h1>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Email</th>
                                <th class="text-center">P. Number</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactist">
                                <td>{{contact.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
                                <td>{{contact.number}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/metro-docs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
```

> Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);function AppCtrl($scope, $http) {
console.log("Hello world from controller.js");

$http.get('/contactlist').success(function (response) {
    console.log("I got the data");
    $scope.contactList = response;
});}
```

> Server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get('/contactList', function (req, res) {
    console.log("I got the request!");

    person1 = {
        name: 'Tim',
        email: 'tim@domain.com',
        number: '(111) 11-11-111'
    };
    person2 = {
        name: 'Rod',
        email: 'rod@domain.com',
        number: '(211) 11-11-111'
    };
    person3 = {
        name: 'Eddie',
        email: 'eddie@domain.com',
        number: '(311) 11-11-111'
    };

    res.json([person1, person2, person3]);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running from port 3000");
```

> This is the error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   [AngularJs Error][1](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.12%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngRoute%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.3.12%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DngRoute%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A417%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A412%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A53)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520x.bootstrap%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A296)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A35%253A46%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520s%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A302)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A34%253A399)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A35%253A63%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520s%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.3.12%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:35:320%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:34:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:35:63%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:34:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ab%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:38:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js:17:381)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your controller is not wired up - you've declared the function, bit not told angular about it. Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello world from controller.js");

    $http.get('/contactlist').success(function (response) {
      console.log("I got the data");
      $scope.contactList = response;
   });
});
```

Also I see no sign of the script tag loading angular, but it must be there to get the error message. Have you remembered also to include ngRoute, with e.g.?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.12%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: Could you paste that into your question so i get the whole thing

Comment: OK. You need to add ngRoute to you script imports

Comment: @RodolfoA.CalvoJaubert How are you getting on?

Comment: It works fine!! There's no error anymore! I will try other things in my code to make sure the code works fine with it. I had to import the angular-route.min.js!

Comment: Sure! What happens now is that the strings person1, person2 y 3 are not showing up in my index.html!!!! This's really weird! There's no error but the strings don't show up!